# Eventos con pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hola estoy haciendo un juego sencillo en python con pygame pero tengo una duda hay alguna manera de que mientras tenga aplastada la tecla el personaje se siga moviendo porque tengo estar aplastando a cada rato la tecla para que se mueva y no se si hay forma de que mientras tenga pulsada la tecla se siga moviendo??
este es el codigo que tengo

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

          
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_a:
                    player.rect.left -= player.speed
```

Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()
      pulsada = pygame.key.get_pressed()
      if pulsada[pygame.K_a]:
          player.rect.left -= player.speed
```

Esta es otra forma de declarar el movimiento donde no es necesario definir si el evento es apretar o soltar ya que se vale del método presionada(get_pressed)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que el evento pygame.KEYDOWN se emite **una sola vez** al presionar la tecla. Cuando se deja de presionar, se emite pygame.KEYUP. Entonces, una opción es registrar cuando se pulsa en una variable booleana, y una vez por ciclo, mientras dicha variable sea True, mantener el movimiento:

```
movimiento_izquierda = False

while True: # bucle general del juego
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_a:
                movimiento_izquierda = True
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_a:
                movimiento_izquierda = False

    # Fuera de la respuesta a eventos, una vez por ciclo:
    if movimiento_izquierda:
        jugador.mover_izquierda()
```

De esta manera, al pulsar la tecla, la variable movimiento_izquierda pasa a ser True, y seguirá teniendo ese valor hasta que la tecla se suelte (y por tanto se emita KEYUP). Mientras movimiento_izquierda valga True, cada frame el jugador se desplazará hacia la izquierda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es leer que tecla se presiono, y mover el personaje, fuera de la cola de eventos.

```
while jugar:
    reloj.tick(60)
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jugar = False
    # Lo leemos fuera de la cola de eventos
    tecla = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # Y fuera de la misma hacemos las acciones
    #tabla_izquierda.mover(tecla)
    #tabla_derecha.mover(tecla)
    #pelota.mover()
```

Asi lo lees una vez por frame, en vez de estar leyendo varias entradas cada frame.

Answer (score 0):

no te entiendo muy bien pero creo que se que intentas decir, puedes intentar esto (no estoy seguro de que funcione):

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

          
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_a:
                    player.rect.left -= player.speed

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_a:
                    player.rect.left -= player.speed
```

Comment: Explica brevemente qué hace tu código: lee [answer]. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás dejar comentarios en las preguntas, para poder pedir aclaraciones al autor.